# What does this notation means in noncommutative case

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I've always used the covariant derivative in coordinate systems, therefore Christoffel symbols were available, and moreover the coordinate basis elements always commute, i.e. if $\{\partial x_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$ is a coordinate basis, I've always have at hand the fact that $$[\partial x_i,\partial x_j]=0.$$ Now I have to work with a non commutative basis, a nonholonomic one to be precise. Then I looked at the wikipedia page for the intrinsic formulas for the covariant derivative (I am not an expert indeed), and the product rule there says that if $U,V$ are two vector fields and $f$ is a function, then
$$\nabla_U(Vf)=f\nabla_UV+V(\nabla_Uf).$$
I'm pretty confident that if the basis were commutative then $$\nabla_U(Vf)=f\nabla_UV+(\nabla_Uf)V.$$ What can I say in the non commutative case?

Sorry if my question is stupid but I really am totally inexperienced in differential geometry.

Best wishes

-Guido-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Remark: I work locally, talking about vectors (and not vector fields) for simplicity.*

The covariant derivative of the $C^1$ function $f$ along the vector $U$ is the function

$$\nabla_U f:=U(f),$$

so it "commutes" with any other vector $V$. 
The expressions  for $\nabla_U(\nabla_V f)$ you wrote are then equivalent.

- Add on

The covariant derivative of a vector $V$ along the vector $U$, i.e. $\nabla_U(V)$ is a vector: it is defined as

$$\nabla_U(V):=(\nabla V)(U),$$

denoting by $\nabla$  a linear connection on the given smooth manifold. The covariant derivative along a given vector can be extended to arbitrary tensors, though: if we consider functions, the definition is the one given above.

Comment: But in the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Formal_definition they use the notation $V f$ also to indicate the directional derivative of a function along $V$. Then it is misleading to choose one or the other alternative above. How should I interprete?

Comment: I see on the same page this sentence: "Given a function $f\,$, the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\mathbf v}f$ coincides with the normal differentiation of a real function in the direction of the vector $v$, usually denoted by ${\mathbf v}f$ and by $df({\mathbf v})$". So the definition coincides with the one in my answer: the notation ${\mathbf v}f$ can be used, this is true, although it is a bit misleading imho.

Comment: If we use local coordinates, selecting a point on the manifolds with coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n)$ with $v=v_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, then $\nabla_v f= v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, which is a function of the $(x_1,...,x_n)$'s themselves. It commutes with any other vector $v=v_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ at $p$.